# Javascript getDate() Method for a Countdown Timer

Tags: javascript, jquery, date, getdate

In Javascript whenever we call the getDate() method a value of 1-31 is returned for the particular day of the month. This creates a problem in my countdown timer when I specify a future date in `var goal` that is greater than 31 which causes the countdown timer to output '12' instead of the number of days that are actually left until the future date.

```
  function twoDigits(number) {return (number < 10 ? '0' : '') + number};

        var goal = "Sun January 01 2012 00:00:01";
        goal = new Date(goal);
        var now = new Date();
        var count = new Date(goal.getTime() - now.getTime());
        var day = count.getDate() -1;
        var hour = count.getHours()-1; 
        var format = twoDigits(day) + ":" + twoDigits(hour) + ":" + twoDigits(count.getMinutes()) + ":" + twoDigits(count.getSeconds());
      $(function () {
        $('#counter').countdown({
          image: 'digits.png',
          startTime: format
        });
      });
```

Any ideas how I could fix this?

Comment: Date.UTC(year,month,day,hours,minutes,seconds,ms)
Calculate the values from obtained millisecs..

Comment: You want to implement CountDown timer. But in your example you use date in the past? Some mistake or ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function padLeft(str,len,char) {
    len=Number(len)||1;
    char=String(char)||" ";
    for(var i=0;i<len;i++)str=char+str;
    return str.substr(str.length-len);
}

//$(document).ready(function() {
    var goal = "Sun January 01 2011 00:00:01";
    goal = new Date(goal);
    var now = new Date();
    var count = goal.getTime() - now.getTime();
    var sign = count/Math.abs(count);
    count = Math.abs(count);
    var days = Math.floor(count/(24*60*60*1000));
    count -= days*24*60*60*1000;
    var hours = Math.floor(count/(60*60*1000));
    count -= hours*60*60*1000;
    var minutes = Math.floor(count/(60*1000));
    count -= minutes*60*1000;
    var secs = Math.floor(count/1000);

    var startTime = days +":"+ padLeft(hours,2,"0") +":"+ padLeft(minutes,2,"0") +":"+ padLeft(secs,2,"0");
    alert(startTime);
    /*
    $("#counter").countdown({
        image: 'digits.png',
        startTime: startTime,
        format: "dd:hh:mm:ss"
    });
    */ 
//}
```

Comment: This should in theory, work perfectly. However, when I used it it conjunction with this countdown timer: http://jquery-countdown.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/index.html it did not work and the display of the digits was erratic. I tried various modifications to no avail. 

Here is the source for the timer: http://jquery-countdown.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/js/jquery.countdown.js

Comment: @GoofBall: what you means: _when I used it it conjunction with this countdown timer_. You use my code to set `startTime` option ? or what?

Comment: Yes. The countdown.js file I sent is the source for making the digits flip and so forth. Your code is meant to set startTime to a future date and then begin countting down.

Comment: @GoofBall. My code can works with dates in future or in the past! For using with countdown plugin I make additions to code. See updated code. I'm not sure, but my tests with countdown plugin from Your link show me one problem: this plugin does not correctly works with times over 99 days, and in some cases it uses 99 secs in minute, 99 minutes in hour, 30 hours in day. According with http://code.google.com/p/jquery-countdown/ this plugin is _beta_. I think what it has buggy code for long time periods.

Comment: You are quite right, my friend. There are still quite a few bugs and display errors. Some people have noted that these issues are related to the style-sheets in the counter div. The original developer of the plugin has gone dark and has not been active for some time. I am going to try working on this again tonight.

Comment: It works for under 100 days. I suppose that is the best that we can hope for at this point. Thanks for all your time, Andrew. :)

Answer (score 0):

This is not an exact fix for your code's issue
but if you want helper methods for dates, take a look at [sugar.js](http://sugarjs.com/)  it has a host of helper methods, like easily calculating the difference in days between now and a given date.
look at [the features page for all date methods](http://sugarjs.com/api/Date)

you could use this function for example:

```
var goal = "Sun January 01 2011 00:00:01";
goal = new Date(goal);
var difference = goal.daysFromNow();
```

`daysFromNow()` is already an alias for `daysUntil()` & `daysSince()` which are for calculating differences in the past or future, daysFromNow() takes care of the past and future at once :)

and that variable would give you the total amount of days, even if it's more than 31 days.

Comment: interesting, never heard of that before. I do find datejs to be nice as well. It's like phps date functions.

Comment: true, but the reason i use sugarjs quite a lot, is the extra features for arrays / objects / functions and even strings or numbers ... if i would only need extra's on dates i would find DateJs enough too...

Comment: @Sander I still need to take a look at this. I will do some time today.